# Change of basis from Chebyshev to monomial basis for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, approximation-theory

I'm not that familiar with Chebyshev polynomials, so I hope I'm not too far off.

Suppose that I have three order pairs $(x_0, f(x_0))$, $(x_1, f(x_1))$, and $(x_2, f(x_2))$ where $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Letting $T_k$ denote the $k$-th Chebyshev polynomial, I can find the interpolating Chebyshev polynomial by solving the matrix equation
\begin{equation}
  \left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  T_0(x_0) & T_1(x_0) & T_2(x_0) \\
  T_0(x_1) & T_1(x_1) & T_2(x_1) \\
  T_0(x_2) & T_1(x_2) & T_2(x_2)
  \end{array}
  \right]
  \left[
  \begin{array}{c}
  c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2
  \end{array}
  \right]
  =
  \left[
  \begin{array}{c}
  f(x_0) \\ f(x_1) \\ f(x_2)
  \end{array}
  \right]
\end{equation}

I have two questions.

First, how can I find the coordinates in the monomial basis? I think this should be conceptually the same as change of basis in Euclidian space even though here we have spaces of functions, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about this.

Second, a paper that I am reading asks for the Chebyshev polynomials of $\log(x)$ - it says that it determines the coefficients for
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_k \pi_k T_k(log(x)).
\end{equation}
Can this be achieved by replacing $x_i$ with $\log(x_i)$ in the matrix above?